# How to execute multiple command in ExecStart

Tags: linux, shell, systemd

I wanted to use systemd to archive some logs periodically. However, it does not work as I wanted it to. According to my test, the second part of in string command failed and I really have no idea what going wrong. Would appreciate if anyone could give me some pointer. Thanks.

**Inside Unit File:**

ExecStart=/bin/tar -zcvf "/var/log/test/$(/bin/date)_syslog_archive.tar.gz" "/tmp/log/"

**Getting error:**

Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

Comment: Use ExecStart to start a shell script; put your logic in there. There's no shell otherwise, so you can't use shell syntax.

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate script is a possible solution, as Charles wrote, or you can run the command with `bash -c` or `sh -c`, like this:

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/tar -zcvf "/var/log/test/$(/bin/date)_syslog_archive.tar.gz" "/tmp/log/"'
```

As an aside, you probably want a `+` parameter of the `date` command, like `date +%s` or `date +%Y%m%d` so that you get something that is suitable for a filename, making it something like this:

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/tar -zcvf "/var/log/test/$(/bin/date +%s)_syslog_archive.tar.gz" "/tmp/log/"'
```

Comment: That is essentially just executing a shell script file with all the logics or warping the chained command. Looks like ExecStart is NOT capable of doing multiple in line command execution.

Comment: Agreed on the "executing a shell script", with the advantage of not having to potentially manage an additional file/script, if you're creating a package or orchestrating the rollout somewhere.